# Building Apple's "Son of Grab" project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to build and study the demo project [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple.

I downloaded the archive and opened the project with Xcode 6.1. Building it fails, with the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ChangeBits", referenced from:
      -[Controller awakeFromNib] in Controller.o
      -[Controller toggleOffscreenWindows:] in Controller.o
      -[Controller toggleDesktopWindows:] in Controller.o
      -[Controller toggleFramingEffects:] in Controller.o
      -[Controller toggleOpaqueImage:] in Controller.o
      -[Controller toggleShadowsOnly:] in Controller.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried changing the base SDK to 10.6 then 10.7, hoping the code relies on an outdated SDK. However it still fails with the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Linking error for inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844729/linking-error-for-inline-functions)

> in Controller.m, line 71, add "static" in front of "inline"